# How to find the index of a list element by comparing it to a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Suppose if I had a list that contains some files, like so:

```py
file_list = ['folder\\text.txt', 'folder\\data.csv', 'folder\\picture.png']
```

And also declared a string:

```py
file = 'text.txt'  #Did not include 'folder\\', intentionally.
```

**How can I grab the index of the file_list by using the 'file' variable?**

I have tried the following:

```py
index = file_list.index(file)
filename = file_list[index]
print(filename)
```

However, I am getting this result:

```
ValueError: 'text.txt' is not in list
```

I've understood why my solution failed but is there an efficient solution for grabbing the index by using the string variable?

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Thanks for your reply, but I am not keen on using Python os module. Is there any module that can be compatible with different operating systems like Linux etc...

Comment: you can implement `basename` on your own by splitting on `'\\'` and taking the last element... posting an answer

Comment: @danny_boy `os.path` is meant to be a cross-platform module with support for both Linux and Windows. You should use it instead of re-inventing the wheels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check each element of `file_list` to findout the index of `file`:

```py
def find_index(file, file_list):
    for idx, file_name in enumerate(file_list):
        if file in file_name:
            print(f"idx:{idx}, file_name:{file_name}")
            return idx


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_list = ['folder\\text.txt', 'folder\\data.csv', 'folder\\picture.png']
    file = 'text.txt'
    idx = find_index(file, file_list)
    if idx:
        print(file_list[idx])
    else:
        print(f"Couldn't find idx of {file} ")
```

**Output:**

```
idx:0, file_name:folder\text.txt
folder\text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you :)

```
file_list = ['folder\\text.txt', 'folder\\data.csv', 'folder\\picture.png']
file = 'data.csv'
flag = True
for i in range(len(file_list)):
    if(file_list[i].find(file)!=-1):
        print("file found at {} position in the list".format(i))
        flag = False
        break
if flag:
    print ("File not found :(")
```

OUTPUT:

```
file found at 0 position in the list
```

Comment: Can you explain the if conditional code? Why did you type: **file_list[i].find(file)!=-1** ?

Comment: I am iterating through the list and comparing with the string, if it finds the file name in the list, it means file is found. Then print the location. i contains the location of the file in the list.

If the file is not found, it will return -1, so comparing the condition with -1.
It is string.find() function that i am using since the list contains strings

Comment: I like the logic but since you are using the find() method, won't it just find the lowest index of the substring? What if there are more csv files but with altered names such as 'data23.csv', 'data_mine.csv' etc. If using find(), won't it just return the lowest index such as 'data'?

Comment: Hello @danny_boy, im using find on file variable which has data.csv, so it searches for the whole name data.csv only, so you wont have problem even if there are multiple files

Answer (score 0):

given you don't want to use `os` module (as you said in the comment), just implement a basic `basename` func based on split.

then, you can use a simple comprehension to create a matching list with just the filenames, and look for the index in it.

```py
def basename(path):
  return path.split('\\')[-1]

file_list = ['folder\\text.txt', 'folder\\data.csv', 'folder\\picture.png']
file = 'text.txt'

file_basename_list = [basename(f) for f in file_list]

index = file_basename_list.index(file)

filename = file_list[index]
print(filename)
```

Output:

```
folder\text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to do this would be:

```py
file_list = ['folder\\text.txt', 'folder\\data.csv', 'folder\\picture.png']
search_file = 'text.txt'
base_path = "folder\\"

def find_file(file_list, search_file, base_path):
    for idx, file in enumerate(file_list):
        if file == base_path+search_file:
            return idx
    return "File Not Found"

print(find_file(file_list, search_file, base_path))
```

If you want to add the `base_path` dynamically then use:

```py
import os.path 

path = 'folder\\'
base_path = os.path.basename(path)
```